# How to update a QPainter pixmap based on QTimer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, qpixmap, qtimer

I would like to continuously rotate a QPainter pixmap every tick based from a QTimer - in this example a clock arm. I can rotate the clock arm, however I dont have the skills to make the rotation dynamic. Here is the clock I would like to make and below is my sample code. Let me know if you can help me on the way, thanks!

[image]

```
import sys
import random 

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.Clock_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("clock.png")
        self.Arm_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("clockarm.png")
        self.painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.Clock_pixmap)
        self.painter.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), self.Arm_pixmap)
        self.painter.end()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.Clock_pixmap.scaled(self.label.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(150, 150) 

        self.w1 = self.Arm_pixmap.width()/2
        self.h1 = self.Arm_pixmap.height()/2

        self.rotationData = random.sample(range(100), 100)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.rotateArm, interval=100)
        timer.start()

        self.n=0

    def rotateArm(self):
        self.n+=1
        self.painter.translate(self.w1,self.h1)
        self.painter.rotate(self.rotationData[self.n])
        self.painter.translate(-self.w1,-self.h1)
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: share the .png please

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic? If you mean smooth, then use small rotation angles with a short timer.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html

Comment: @eyllanesc Here is the images: Clock: imgur.com/myq8Bf5 Clockarm: imgur.com/FAQibFt Joe: I would like the rotation to follow a specific list of data (self.rotationData) every tick. It doesn't have to be a smooth motion - but it would be preferable. Also, it has to be those two specific images, so the analogclock example wont work - but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are painting on a QPainter where you indicated that it was finished painting since you used the `end()` method. So it is not necessary to make a class attribute to QPainter but only a local variable. Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys
import random

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._angle = 0

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.clock_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("clock.png")
        self.arm_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("clockarm.png")

        rotation_data = random.sample(range(100), 100)
        self.data_iter = iter(rotation_data)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.rotate_arm, interval=100)
        timer.start()

    def rotate_arm(self):
        try:
            angle = next(self.data_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        else:
            self.draw(angle)

    def draw(self, angle):
        pixmap = self.clock_pixmap.copy()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.setRenderHints(
            QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform
        )
        painter.translate(pixmap.rect().center())
        painter.rotate(angle)
        painter.translate(-pixmap.rect().center())
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), self.arm_pixmap)
        painter.end()
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```